# Difference between graph_pb2.GraphDef and tf.GraphDef

Tags: tensorflow

What is the difference between graph_pb2.GraphDef and tf.GraphDef?

Are these two equivalent? If not, how are they different, which one should I use?

```
with open("input.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

with open("input.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
```